# How to get the values from the drop down list using php?

Tags: php, html

```
<select name='car1'>
     <option value='1'>Toyota</option>
     <option value='2'>Honda</option>
     <option value='3'>Ford</option>
</select>

<input type='submit' name='submitform' />

if(isset($_POST['submitform'])){
    $Getvalue = $_POST['car1'];
    echo $Getvalue;
}
```

How do I get the values (Toyota, Honda, and Ford) not the numbers

Comment: have you considered replacing the values inside the options? that might work

Comment: For instance you should use jQuery to get the affordable values you want. The Values From dropdown are just the "value", what you want is the option label from select, it's not combined to php.

Comment: `value='Toyota'` etc?

Comment: I am currently using those values for another functions, I just need to get the values (Toyota) that is all. I understand what you guys mean... value='toyota', then use my code to echo it out, but I am doing something different

Answer (score 2):

In POST you receive only submitted value, so you should use

```
<option value="Toyota">Toyota</option>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use it.

```
<select name='car1'>
  <option value='Toyota'>Toyota</option>
  <option value='Honda'>Honda</option>
  <option value='Ford'>Ford</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you could, you could use jquery in this one. You need another container for that 'Name'. Consider this example:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['car1'])) {
    $id = $_POST['car1'];
    $name = $_POST['selected'];
    echo $name;
}

?>

<form method="POST" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="selected" value="" />
    <select name='car1'>
        <option value='1'>Toyota</option>
        <option value='2'>Honda</option>
        <option value='3'>Ford</option>
        </select>
</form>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('select[name="car1"]').change(function(){
        // as you select your pick, 
        // this will append the name inside the hidden input
        var selected = $(this).val();
        var value = $('select[name="car1"] option[value="'+selected+'"]').text();
        $(this).prev('input[name="selected"]').attr('value', value);
        $('form').submit();
    });

});
</script>
```

[**Sample Fiddle**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/CiIALa)

Comment: @user3684783 Your welcome. I just thought maybe you really cant remove/replace the values inside the `<option>`, this can also be your option.

Answer (score 0):

Only option values will be send in $_POST. If you don't need values in numbers, replace them with text values.

```
<select name='car1'>
 <option value='Toyota'>Toyota</option>
 <option value='Honda'>Honda</option>
 <option value='Ford'>Ford</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Web-browser send to web-server post line like "car1=1&submitform=". Php script does not known about what inside `options`. Change values to:

```
<select name='car1'>
     <option value='Toyota'>Toyota</option>
     <option value='Honda'>Honda</option>
     <option value='Ford'>Ford</option>
</select>
```